# Получение значений с нескольких "id"

Tags: javascript, html

Есть таблица, которую заполняет пользователь. В конце каждой строки нужно получить некий итог. Хочу понять, как заставить яваскрипт работать в рамках одной текущей строки? И как его ему передать номер строки?

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>Товар</th>
    <th>Цена за кг</th>
    <th>Количество</th>
    <th>Стоимость</th>
    <th>Расчитать</th>
  </tr>
  <tr id="row0">
    <td id="good0">Яблоки</td>
    <td><input id="price0" type="text"></td>
    <td>
      <select id="qty0">
        <option value="0">-</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td id="cost0">0</td>
    <td><button onclick="jsfunc()">OK</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="row1">
    <td id="good1">Груши</td>
    <td><input id="price1" type="text"></td>
    <td>
      <select id="qty1">
        <option value="0">-</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td id="cost1">0</td>
    <td><button onclick="jsfunc()">OK</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Есть еще мысль присвоить каждой ячейке id в формате (номер строки, номер столбца) `id="12"`, например. Но как это сообщить скирпту через кнопку?

Comment: стоит добавить скрипт

Comment: У вас грубейшая ошибка в коде! ID он на то и ID чтобы быть УНИКАЛЬНЫМ! Во всем DOMe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ID должны быть уникальны - поэтому заменим повторяющиеся на классы.

Кнопку *ОК* жать не обязательно и утомительно: пусть лучше результат обновляется сразу, по изменению полей. Для этого надо слушать события – у input'ов цены и количества.

Каждый `<input>` сидит в `<td>`, а ячейка, в свою очередь, в строке `<tr>`. Имея `input` получаем строку – это родитель родителя. Имея строку, находим по именам класса в ней оба `input`, берём их значения и перемножаем. Результат записываем в ячейку с классом `cost` внутри этой строки.

```js
// по имени класса и имени события находим элементы
// и вешаем на них слушателем события ф-ю calculate()
function addEL( className, eventName) {
  var i, els = document.getElementsByClassName(className);
  for(i=0; i<els.length; i++) {
    els[i].addEventListener(eventName, calculate);
  }
}

addEL('price', 'input');
addEL('qty', 'change');

function calculate(e){
  var row = e.target.parentNode.parentNode;
  var price = row.querySelector('.price').value;
  var qty = row.querySelector('.qty').value;
  row.querySelector('.cost').innerText = price * qty;
}
```

```css
table{border-collapse: collapse}table,td,th{border-color:#CCC}
```

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>Товар</th>
    <th>Цена за кг</th>
    <th>Количество</th>
    <th>Стоимость</th>
  </tr>
  <tr id="row0">
    <td class="product">Яблоки</td>
    <td><input class="price" type="number"></td>
    <td>
      <select class="qty">
        <option value="0">-</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td class="cost">0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="row1">
    <td class="product">Груши</td>
    <td><input class="price" type="number"></td>
    <td>
      <select class="qty">
        <option value="0">-</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td class="cost">0</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: К индексу подвязывать не очень хорошо, т.к. HTML может измениться в любой момент и потом все полетит и будет не правильно выводить информацию, касательно того, что просто порвет сам HTML

Comment: @Shnur, true that, спасибо. Переписал через querySelector()

Answer (score 1):

С закрытым селектом, заменой id на class, т.к. id должен быть уникален и для упрощения самого скрипта. добавлена защита от пустого значения.

```js
var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

if (!Element.prototype.matches) Element.prototype.matches = Element.prototype.msMatchesSelector;
if (!Element.prototype.closest) Element.prototype.closest = function (selector) {
 var el = this;
 while (el) {
  if (el.matches(selector)) {
   return el;
  }
  el = el.parentElement;
 }
};

[].forEach.call(inputs, function(input) {
 input.addEventListener('input', function(){
  var val = this.value;
  var newValue = val.replace(/[^0-9.]/gi, '');
  var valueDiff = val.length - newValue.length;
  if (valueDiff) {
   this.value = newValue;
  }
 });
});

[].forEach.call(buttons, function(button) {
 button.addEventListener('click', function(e){
  var tr = this.closest('tr');
  var price = tr.getElementsByClassName('price')[0].value || 0;
  var qty = tr.getElementsByClassName('qty')[0].value || 0;
  var cost = price * qty;
  tr.getElementsByClassName('cost')[0].innerText = cost;

  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
 });
});
```

```html
<table border="1">
<tr>
 <th>Товар</th>
 <th>Цена за кг</th>
 <th>Количество</th>
 <th>Стоимость</th>
 <th>Расчитать</th>
</tr>
<tr id="row0">
 <td id="good0">Яблоки</td>
 <td><input class="price" type="text"></td>
 <td>
  <select class="qty">
   <option value="0">-</option>
   <option value="1">1</option>
   <option value="2">2</option>
  </select>
 </td>
 <td class="cost">0</td>
 <td><button class="btn">OK</button></td>
</tr>
<tr id="row1">
 <td id="good1">Груши</td>
 <td><input class="price" type="text"></td>
 <td>
  <select class="qty">
   <option value="0">-</option>
   <option value="1">1</option>
   <option value="2">2</option>
  </select>
 </td>
 <td class="cost">0</td>
 <td><button class="btn">OK</button></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: почему `innerHTML`, а не `innerText` – там же число, а не разметка; `type=text` допускает ввод валидных значений `0xFF` (норм.) и не очень `FF` => "NaN"; наконец, для чего `preventDefault()` и ко.?

Comment: select и так закрыт.

Comment: Да спасибо, пропустил этот момент. и ко, больше как защита от дурака, т.к. кнопка без типа и может запустить форму, в которую этот код может быть обернут, ну или если будут использовать тег "а", что тоже за собой повлечет перезагрузку страницы.

Comment: @ikerya я очень Вам рекомендую быть внимательным(ой) т.к. я редактировал пост и Ваш и самого автора.

Comment: @Shnur Возможно, у нас разные понимания, что такое select? http://prntscr.com/bjp6e7

Comment: @Shnur дело ещё в том, что когда предложили правку к посту, я её модифицировал, убрав ID-шники у элементов.

Comment: @Sergiks спасибо, добавил проверку для IE, вечно про него забываю... что он вообще существует.

Comment: в цену нельзя ввести десятичную точку, хотел на пол-рубля скидку дать )

Answer (score -1):

Можно кнопке добавить атрибут data-id, который означает id tr-элемента (row0, row1...):

```js
function jsfunc(parent) {
  var id = parent.getAttribute("data-id");

  var price = document.getElementById("row" + id).getElementsByTagName("td")[1].getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;
  var num = document.getElementById("row" + id).getElementsByTagName("td")[2].getElementsByTagName("select")[0].value;

  var cost = parseInt(price * num);

  document.getElementById("row" + id).getElementsByTagName("td")[3].innerHTML = cost;
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>Товар</th>
    <th>Цена за кг</th>
    <th>Количество</th>
    <th>Стоимость</th>
    <th>Расчитать</th>
  </tr>
  <tr id="row0">
    <td>Яблоки</td>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
    <td>
      <select>
        <option value="0">-</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td><button data-id="0" onclick="jsfunc(this)">OK</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="row1">
    <td>Груши</td>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
    <td>
      <select>
        <option value="0">-</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td><button data-id="1" onclick="jsfunc(this)">OK</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Вы бы ошибки хоть исправили... т.к. это работать не будет

Comment: @Shnur попробуйте нажать на кнопку `Выполнить код`. Я уверен, у Вас получится. Я не собираюсь делать глобальные перемены в коде автора. Пусть он лучше сделает это сам, как ему будет удобнее, а потом, если нужно будет, обратится на SO за помощью ещё раз. Я дал автору пример, как можно сделать. Научитесь думать, а потом минусуйте и меня и автора. Мы пришли сюда, чтобы научиться, и я думаю, что стоит указать на проблему автора, а не минусовать его сразу. Все мы делали и делаем ошибки и ничего в этом страшного нету.

Comment: Так вот и научите и покажите ему где он сделал ошибки, а то плодите одни и те же ошибки и ни кто ничему не учиться. а только копипаст делают тех же ошибок. потому и минус.

Comment: Исправил ошибки.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41514/discussion-between-ikerya-and-shnur).